# Where can I see the bonus of Warhelm of Kassar?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

I found a helmet the other day called [Warhelm of Kassar](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/warhelm-of-kassar), which has a great bonus to Phalanx.

I've since 'cubed' this item to get it's power, and have the bonus of "Reduce the cooldown and increase the damage of Phalanx by 60%."

However, when I open the details on my character, I can only see, 'Phalanx damage bonus 20%' which is from the Lord Commander passive.

Is this correct? Is this an invisible bonus? The recharge is definitely having an effect, but why don't I see 80% dmg bonus to Phalanx in my details?

Comment: I can't find anyone reporting it not actually working, so it seems likely that yes, it is an invisible bonus. Try it out for yourself and come back with the answer :) (with screenshots of damage numbers and your inventory screen if you feel ambitious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a bit of rudimentary experimentation using a timer and the game, I can confirm that the recharge does work at least.

It reduced the recharge of the skill down to around 12 seconds.

Although I still can't see a visual indication of this in the game interface.